# Backbone js Connecting to Server

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js, client-side, server-side

How can we send HTTP requests to the server using backbone js ?
for example I have an external url to use for sending my GET,POST,PUT,DELETE requests :)
thanks for your answer

**Answer:**

you we should put the url in the url of collection and backbone will automatically send the HTTP requests to the server :)
thanks by the way

Comment: This question is too broad to answer specifically.  Please post the code you are having problem with and consider splitting into multiple questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want work with server you need to handle all this queries **GET, POST, PUT, DELETE** on the server side. Because backbone use them all. Also the best way is to use some framework that supports **REST API**.

> Here is the simple example on PHP:
>   https://medium.com/@scottdixon/backbone-js-with-php-mysql-362b07dad844#.o994tknvu
>
> And useful book, how to develop backbone apps
>   https://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/

Comment: I use php laravel for server side and It does have controls 
but when I ham form and some inputs when my user fill in their information how should I handle it in backbone to send to PHP?

Comment: @SaminFakharian, as far as I know, you need to define an **url** in your backbone **model** and **event** responsible for your form. Wen submit action will successful, event function must get data from submit form and save them into your model. And wen model will save data, it will automatically send data to laravel via defined **url**

Comment: I just want to review my undrestanding
you say that I should define a property name url and set it with the link given to me
and add an event that when I push the button It should go to my url?
+

Comment: I don't get you clearly about the link. When you push the button event function must get form data and save it (`this.model.save({ title: this.$('#title').val() })`). You don't need worry about how send data to the server, backbone do it by self. You see, url parameter in the model it's just like url in ajax, so you don't need to define action in html form.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers
can you give me a reference that I can learn about these things?

Comment: Check first link from my answer above, there you will see simple example.